# Passing data from a Excel form to a new spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I´m trying something new in Excel. Just as new as I am to VBA, so please bear with me.

I have a form with a bunch of things on it.. one item is a button that opens a spreadsheet. I would like to pass information from the form to the newly opened spreadsheet but am running against a wall. I did the following..

Declared a public variable right at the top of the form

```
Public instno As String
```

then on the initialization of the form I assign a value to this string from the current worksheet.

```
Sub UserForm_Initialize()
instno = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "J").Value
' other stuff in here too, this is just for this problem...
End Sub
```

Now the code for the button that opens the new workbook and that I am trying to pass the value to.

```
Private Sub CMB2_Click() 
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application 
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
xlApp.Visible = True 
xlApp.Workbooks.Open Filename:="G:\tracking.xlsm"
Cells(13, "E").Value = instno 'data should go into cell E13
End Sub
```

Does not work for me, any suggestions ? The workbook opens fine, just can´t get the data into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing this in Excel, then you do not need to `CreateObject` every time. See this example. Also when you are working with objects, fully qualify them.

```
Dim instno As String

Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    '~~> Though I am not in favor of `ActiveCell`. Use the actual cell address
    instno = ws.Range("J" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
End Sub

Private Sub CMB2_Click()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="G:\tracking.xlsm")
    '~~> Change this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    ws.Range("E13").Value = instno
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP**

If you wan to follow the `CreateObject` way then try this

```
Dim instno As String

Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim wsThis As Workbook
    Set wsThis = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    '~~> Though I am not in favor of `ActiveCell`. Use the actual cell address
    instno = ws.Range("J" & ActiveCell.Row)
End Sub

Private Sub CMB2_Click()
    Dim xlApp As Object, xlWb As Object, xlWs As Object

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Visible = True

    Set xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename:="G:\tracking.xlsm")
    '~~> Change this to the relevant worksheet
    Set xlWs = xlWb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    xlWs.Range("E13").Value = instno
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Siddharth, Doing it your way keeps the form ontop and the new workbook behind and inaccesible. Once I cancel the form, the data is displayed. now need to fiddle to see how i can get it to work, unless you have a quick answer.

Comment: Yup :). Open the userform in Modeless Mode... `Userform1.Show vbModeless`

Comment: if i do the modeless mode, none of the checkboxes or the textboxes are active. So that does not work either. :(

Comment: That's strange. it shouldn't happen. May I see your workbook? BTW, I have updated the code above to show you how to do it vis the `CreateObject` way. You will have to refresh the page

Comment: BINGO... Working like a charm now. Thanks for the help. I would never have figured this out.